# asp.net web not accepting List of objects but accepts same list when wrapped into other class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have one api method,i pass "/api/stocks/1/images/" and list of stockimage as json. I am getting stockImages below as null (function's input parameter)

```
[Route("api/stocks/{stockId}/images")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(int stockId, [FromBody]List<StockImage> stockImages)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

When i pass `/api/stocks/1/images/` and list of stockimage as `json` and wrap it in a class and not accept list directly, I am able to see stockImages prefilled (function's input parameter)

I have one api method

```
[Route("api/stocks/{stockId}/images")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(int stockId, [FromBody]Temp stockImages)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

public class Temp
{
    public List<StockImage> stockImages {get; set;}
}
```

Do i need to have this Temp wrapper class or is there any way to avoid this?

Adding sample json:

```
{  
   "stockImages":[  
            {  
               "imgId" : 8908,
               "imgURL": "http://imgd5.aeplcdn.com/cw/Volkswagen-Polo-Comfortline-4319619.jpg",
               "altText":"Honda City Exterior Photos",
               "title":"Honda City Exterior Photos",
               "defaultImg":true
            }
      ]   
}
```

Comment: can you show the json you are sending ?

Comment: To make your desired method signature work, how about just sending the array without the stockImages declaration? e.g. `{[  
            {  
               "imgId" : 8908,
               "imgURL": "http://imgd5.aeplcdn.com/cw/Volkswagen-Polo-Comfortline-4319619.jpg",
               "altText":"Honda City Exterior Photos",
               "title":"Honda City Exterior Photos",
               "defaultImg":true
            }
      ]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is you are wrapping the array inside an object . remove it and you are good to go

```
[  
        {  
           "imgId" : 8908,
           "imgURL": "http://imgd5.aeplcdn.com/cw/Volkswagen-Polo-Comfortline-4319619.jpg",
           "altText":"Honda City Exterior Photos",
           "title":"Honda City Exterior Photos",
           "defaultImg":true
        }
  ]
```

Comment: Just one thing, which do you think is right approach- passing array within object or without wrapper object- convention wise?

Comment: @sahil , i dont see a need to wrap an array in another object unless you intend to pass some other metadata related to the array along with it.